# rowspan found then check first cell have text or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have HTML table. I'm looping through table and iterate over each row whose third cell has a rowspan attribute.
How I check if rowspan is found then check its first cell have text or not. If yes then assign to javascript variable.

```
for (var i = 0; row = myTable.rows[i]; i++) {
    if( row.cells[2].hasAttribute("rowspan") {

    }
}




 <table id="myTable">
    <tr>
    <td>cell1</td>
    <td>cell2</td>
    <td>cell3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>cell4</td>
    <td>cell5</td>
    <td rowspan="2">cell6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>cell8</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>cell9</td>
    <td>cell10</td>
    <td>cell11</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use *innerText* (and *trim* if you like to ignore whitespace):

```
if (row.cells[2].getAttribute('rowspan') != null) {
    if (row.cells[2].innerText.trim() != "") {
        myJavascriptVar = row.cells[2].innerText.trim();
    }
}
```

Comment: @user1481713 hm, I guess maybe some browsers (*cough* IE7 *cough*) don't support it.  You should definitely be able to use *getAttribute* though.